# « Louper » : nuance entre rater/manquer et laisser échapper etc. ?

Tags: sens, argot, origine-ou-raison, registre, citations

> Comme le Sénat ajourne ses travaux jeudi et que les sénateurs ne
>   rentreront pas au boulot avant le 19 février, Julie Miville-Dechêne
>   estime que la chambre haute a **loupé** « une occasion de se prononcer
>   dans des délais raisonnables ».
>
> [ [*Sénat: motion pour les Franco-Ontariens bloquée*](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/politique/politique-canadienne/201812/13/01-5207928-senat-motion-pour-les-franco-ontariens-bloquee.php), dans *La
>   presse*, 13 décembre 2018, je souligne ]

Le verbe *louper* signifiant rater est qualifié de [*familier*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/familier/32794?q=familier#32712) au [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/louper), au [Larousse en ligne](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/louper/47907?q=louper#47827), au [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/louper) et au DHLF, où on nous dit qu'il est d'abord attesté dans l'argot des typographes (1835) pour « mal exécuter un travail » ; ce serait à partir du sens de « mal faire » que découlent ceux de *manquer* et *rater*, y compris celui de « laisser échapper » de 1915 (DHLF).

- Peut-on expliquer ou illustrer la nuance entre le sens (ou l'emploi
  de) de *rater/manquer* et celui de *laisser échapper* ; peut-on
  employer *louper* pour [*laisser*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/laisser/1) s'échapper ; de quel sens de *louper* s'agit-il dans l'extrait ?
- Y a-t-il une raison particulière qui explique pourquoi le deuxième
  sens est relié au premier près d'un siècle plus tard ; l'attestation
  de l'argot des [soldats](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/louper) de 1915 est-elle reliée ?
- Le verbe louper est-il vraiment familier ou est-il davantage courant
  qu'avant ; son emploi est-il surprenant dans (le texte de) l'extrait (la presse écrite) ; pense-t-on que dans de tels cas le verbe précédant la citation fasse généralement partie des propos de la personne citée ?

Comment: La presse écrite est connue pour la popularisation d'erreurs de syntaxe et de formulations douteuses, ça ne me choque pas plus que ça de voir un mot d'argot dans un texte "sérieux".

Comment: *"Peut-on expliquer ou illustrer la nuance entre ... "* - je ne comprends pas, les définitions de chaque emploi données en lien ne sont pas assez claires ? "*pourquoi le deuxième sens est relié au premier près d'un siècle plus tard*" - il ne me semble pas qu'il s'agisse d'un "lien" établi entre deux emplois déjà existants mais plutôt d'un nouvel emploi apparu plus tard, comme cela se produit fréquemment.

Comment: @guillaume31 Merci ! C'est pourquoi j'ai indiqué « ou l'emploi de » ; je suis francophone mais je n'utilise pas ce verbe même si je le comprends... son emploi m'est étranger. Si on oublie un moment les sciences et la technologie, le début du 20e et en particulier le moment de la 1ère est-il productif : j'essaye d'explorer ça directement par cet exemple. Mais peut-être qu'il n'y a rien à dire de particulier à cet effet alors votre propos pourrait répondre à cet élément là...

Answer (score 3):

Une simple comparaison des fréquences d'utilisation de ces quatre termes, tous sens inclus, montre que « louper » et « laisser échapper » sont très peu usités en comparaison avec « rater » et surtout « manquer », qui est de loin le plus usité.

**1.**

**A/** **Peut-on expliquer ou illustrer la nuance entre le sens (ou l'emploi de) de rater/manquer et celui de laisser échapper ?**

Dans le contexte d'une occasion  il y a une nuance mais si ténue dans certains cas qu'on se demande s'il faut vraiment en tenir compte. Comme je la perçois, il n'est pas question d'autre chose que d'un état d'esprit propre à la personne qui « laisse échapper », cet état d'esprit faisant défaut à la personne qui « manque » ou « rate » et n'étant qu'une plus ou moins grande conscience de la réalité d'une occasion possible ; cela trouve une confirmation dans le [sens](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=3860409810;) de « échapper » qui est à prendre en compte ici :  « (TLFi) 1. Cesser d'être pris ou retenu. ». Pourquoi ne pas accepter le [second sens possible](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=3860409810;) de « échapper » , c'est à dire « Ne pas être pris. » ? Il n'y a pas trop d'indications qui puissent justifier ce choix ; j'en trouve une dans l'utilisation de la forme verbale « laisser échapper » dans un autre contexte et je suppose qu'il s'agit de la même idée ; cet autre contexte c'est celui de l'expression « [laisser échapper un propos](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/laisser%20%C3%A9chapper) » (émettre un propos malgré soi) : le propos est évidemment « pris », « retenu », pour qu'il puisse être émis.

**Exemples** (dus à mon imagination)

- Il avait été prévenu de la posssibilité de contacter un service avant une date limite ; cela aurait pu lui permettre éventuellement de régulariser sa situation à courte échéance ;  il a attendu, ne sachant pas quels risques il courrait, ne sachant que faire, dans l'indécision, et a finalement <s>manqué/raté</s>/laissé échapper cette opportunité. (*Il semble préférable de ne pas utiliser « manquer » ou « rater ».*)
- Ce contribuable bénéficiait d'une réduction d'impot à condition de fournir des justificatifs en temps opportun ; il s'y est pris en temps voulu pour faire les démarches en vue d'obtenir les justificatifs mais des lenteurs administratives ont fait qu'il n'a pas pu fournir les papiers demandés avant la date limite ; comme on ne peut pas vraiment conclure qu'il ait manqué/raté/laissé échapper cette opportunité d'une réduction, ne peut-on pas invoquer sur le plan de la légalité un tort qui lui a été fait et obtenir un redressement? (*Il semble que l'on puisse aussi utiliser « manquer » ou « rater » bien que « laisser échapper » paraisse légèrement préférable.*)

**B/** **De quel sens de louper s'agit-il dans l'extrait ?**

(TLFi) I.  Emploi trans.| B.  Qqn loupe qqc./qqn |1. Qqn loupe qqc. **Ne pas réussir à profiter de, à saisir une occasion**; ne pas arriver à temps pour.

Il s'agit de ce sens, évidemment parce qu'il est question de louper une occasion donc de louper quelque chose et que le sens « A » implique qu'il s'agit d'une opération qui tourne mal ou qu'i n'aboutit pas.

**C/** **peut-on employer « louper » pour « laisser s'échapper » ?**

Dans la mesure où « louper » est considéré n'être qu'un synonyme de « manquer » et « rater » dans le sens ci-dessus ((TLFi) **rater** II.  Empl. trans. Qqn rate qqc., qqn. Synon. fam. louper.; **manquer** A.  Manquer qqc. Synon. fam. louper, rater.), on peut employer « louper » à la place de « laisser s'échapper » selon que l'on peut employer « manquer » ou « rater » à sa place, ce qui est le sujet du « **A** ».

**2.**

La nature commune des deux sens est dans leur propre de caractériser l'échec ; je ne suis conscient d'aucun principe qui explique ce « glissement » du sens sauf celui  d'un rapprochement dans la pensée humaine, ce rapprochement ayant été inspiré seulement par l'idée d'échec commune aux deux contextes.

**3**

- D'après la courbe de [fréquence d'utilisation de « louper »](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=louper&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clouper%3B%2Cc0) il existe une augmentation constante et importante de son utilisation depuis environ 1950. Cependant, mon impression est que le mot reste un terme familier ; il ne semble pas figurer dans le vocabulaire standard ; il semble que beaucoup de monde préfère toujours entendre « réussir ses plats » plutôt que « ne pas louper ses plats » ou « ne pas réussir à un examen » plutôt « louper un examen ».
- Par rapport à la presse telle que l'on peut s'en faire une idée en France il n'y a rien de surprenant.
- Du point de vue du contexte culturel français, même si celui-ci est caractérisé je crois par des standards linguistiques plus relâchés dans la presse que dans le monde politique, il ne serait pas véritablement surprenant d'entendre ce mot de la bouche d'un personnage politique jusque dans ses propos assez formels ; après tout ce n'est plus de l'argot mais un terme familier sans connotations vulgaires (an contraire de « foirer », par exemple, lequel mot serait surprenant, franchement une cause d'irritation, qui que soit le locuteur qui l'utiliserait).

Comment: Merci ! Mais donc vous dites au final qu'on ne peut dire _le gardien a loupé un prisonnier en cellule_ ou _l'oiseau a loupé de sa cage_ ? Dans votre premier exemple, vous semble-t-il préférable de ne pas utiliser rater/manquer uniquement à cause de l'état d'esprit dont vous traitez s'y trouverait et qui rend préférable l'emploi de laisse échapper ? Votre notion d'état d'esprit, est-ce comparable à la (plus grande) proximité de l'occasion, à perdre ce qu'on a en main ou quasiment, ce qu'on possède  ?

Comment: @Saint-Jacques En effet,  ces deux phrases ne me laissent  pas perplexe, elle m'apparaissent d'emblée comme n'ayant aucun sens en elles-mêmes. Elles pourraient avoir un sens cependant dans un contexte particulier. dans le premier exemple la personne a la situation en main, elle sait qu'il y a une possibilité et elle connait la date et elle tergiverse en laissant passer le temps, plutôt désemparée, jusqu'à ce qu'il soit trop tard ; l'opportunité qu'elle avait de façon consciente, qu'elle retenait (pour ainsi dire) elle l'a perdu, elle l'a laissé s'échapper.

Comment: @Saint-Jacques Je vois, vous appelez cela « proximité » ; c'est ce que j'appelle  « conscience » ou « nescience » ; « perdre ce que l'on a en main » est l'idée. La personne qui ne bénéficie pas d'une réduction de taxe parce qu'elle n'a lu nulle part qu'elle y avait droit, parce qu'elle n'a jamais entendu parler de cela selon mon point de vue est une personne qui rate, qui manque une opportunité, plutôt qu'une personne qui laisse échapper une opportunité ; si cette personne connait cet avantage qu'elle peut avoir mais qu'elle se débrouille mal et ne fait pas ce qu'il faut alors (continué)

Comment: @Saint-Jacques elle laisse échapper une opportunité ; cependant, je le fais remarquer, on peut aussi dire « manquer/rater », et ne pas prendre en compte cette nuance dans ce cas-là ; gardez néanmoins à l'esprit que ceci est essentiellement mon point de vue, faute d'avoir pu en trouver un de parfaitement établi, et que vous devriez continuer à le considérer d'un œil critique.

Answer (score 2):

Sans chercher à répondre aux questions, juste pour rendre hommage au très savant **Gérard Genette** qui, je ne sais plus dire dans quel travail précis, s'est intéressé dans le détail au très riche vocabulaire de l'échec en tous genres.

Et surtout citer sa conclusion amusante qu'il livre dans '*Apostille*' :

*«...depuis Homère, la défaite (La chute de Troie, le massacre de Roncevaux, la retraite de Russie...) est plus sympathique, paradoxalement plus glorieuse, et en tout cas plus poiétogénique ou pour le moins logogénique que la victoire.»*