# Rater / louper / manquer/ échapper et "missing something"

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, synonymes

[I have seen the relevant question here 
[« Louper » : nuance entre rater/manquer et laisser échapper etc. ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32994/louper-nuance-entre-rater-manquer-et-laisser-%c3%a9chapper-etc) ]

> What am I missing here? (implying a failure to reach a purpose)

Quel verbe rend mieux le sens de la phrase ci-dessus

> Qu'est-ce que je loupe/rate/manque ici ?
>   Qu'est-ce qui m’échappe ici ?

Voici un exemple d'emploi : "The diagram indicates that there is convergence, right? Why the program does not stop? What am I missing here?"

Comment: What purpose was missed?

Comment: @jlliagre Voici par exemple en emploi : "The diagram indicates that there is convergence, right? Why the program does not stop? What am I missing here?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the context provided in your comment:

> The diagram indicates that there is convergence, right? Why doesn't the program stop? What am I missing here?

The third sentence might have two slightly different meanings.

If you are involved in the failure (you wrote the program, you supplied the data...):

> *Qu'est-ce que j'ai raté/loupé/manqué ?* (spoken French)

(Colloquial: *Où est-ce que j'ai merdé ?*)

If you just fail to get the logic of what you observe:

> *Qu'est-ce qui m'échappe ?* (formal)

(Spoken: *Je suis passé à côté d'un truc ?*) Thanks to Teleporting Goat

(Colloquial: *C'est quoi qui se passe, là ?*)

Comment: J'ajouterais "*Je suis passé à côté d'un truc ?*"